# debian bullseye unable to unlock mate-screensaver

Tags: debian, mate-desktop

I'm running debian bullseye (was a fresh install but with old $HOME) and mate desktop.
Whenever I lock my Notebook with mate-screensaver; I can not unlock it neither with my main user nor an unmodified testuser.

In journal I found

```
journalctl | grep mate-screensaver
Dez 19 18:06:28 Taomon dbus-daemon[541]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.70' (uid=1000 pid=2931 comm="mate-screensaver-preferences ")
Dez 19 18:06:28 Taomon pulseaudio[806]: Looking for .desktop file for mate-screensaver-preferences
Dez 19 18:06:28 Taomon pulseaudio[806]: Found /usr/share/applications/mate-screensaver-preferences.desktop.
Dez 19 18:06:28 Taomon pulseaudio[806]: Parsing configuration file '/usr/share/applications/mate-screensaver-preferences.desktop'
Dez 19 18:08:33 Taomon mate-screensaver-dialog[3008]: pam_unix(mate-screensaver:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=1000 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=  user=alex
Dez 19 18:08:50 Taomon pulseaudio[806]: Looking for .desktop file for mate-screensaver-dialog
Dez 19 18:08:50 Taomon mate-screensaver-dialog[3008]: pam_unix(mate-screensaver:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=1000 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=  user=alex
Dez 19 18:09:02 Taomon pulseaudio[806]: Freed 17 "mate-screensaver-dialog"
Dez 19 18:16:23 Taomon mate-screensaver-dialog[3987]: pam_unix(mate-screensaver:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1001 euid=1001 tty=:0 ruser= rhost user=alex
```

My workaround ist to hit STR+Alt+F1 and unlock it there with

```
mate-screensaver-command -u
```

If it matters display-manager is lightdm

```
gsettings list-recursively org.mate.screensaver
org.mate.screensaver themes ['screensavers-personal-slideshow', 'screensavers-popsquares', 'screensavers-gnomelogo-floaters', 'screensavers-footlogo-floaters', 'screensavers-cosmos-slideshow']
org.mate.screensaver embedded-keyboard-command ''
org.mate.screensaver user-switch-enabled true
org.mate.screensaver status-message-enabled true
org.mate.screensaver embedded-keyboard-enabled false
org.mate.screensaver logout-command ''
org.mate.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
org.mate.screensaver lock-enabled false
org.mate.screensaver logout-enabled false
org.mate.screensaver power-management-delay 30
org.mate.screensaver logout-delay 120
org.mate.screensaver cycle-delay 10
org.mate.screensaver lock-delay 1
org.mate.screensaver mode 'random'
org.mate.screensaver picture-filename '/usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-background'
org.mate.screensaver lock-dialog-theme 'default'
```

I have no idea where to start. (maybe pkaction or pam?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it.

The group for /etc/shadow and /etc/gshadow was wrong set to root.

After changing to shadow I can pass the mate-screensaver.

[inspiration](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=663227)

Answer (score 0):

You and I have had similar problems，when I modified the permissions of the/etc/shadow file to 400

When I lock the screen during idle timeout, I cannot enter the desktop after entering the correct password

I can only access the desktop by using the root user through the switch user button.

**Error is found by viewing auth.log**

```
mate-screensaver-dialog:PAM adding faulty module pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

I added capabilities to the/usr/lib/mate screensaver dialog file

```
setcap cap_dac_override+ep /usr/lib/mate-screensaver-dialog
```

Then I continued to lock the screen. And use ordinary users to enter the correct password. OK, I can enter the desktop.

So you can try

Comment: Nope I think in my case it is unix_chkpwd faile for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your offer，After reading the `inspiration`, I think the problem is basically the same, mainly due to the permission problem.

Bypassing permissions or reconfiguring can solve this problem. Therefore, the main focus should be on how to access the file when the program is in use, and the relationship between the owner and the group.

Thanks for the exchange, the problem has been solved.

But I think It may not be a safe way, use `capabilities` ?
Let the program ignore the restrictions of the access control policy

Comment: I restored tis files because uf abug durung ibstallation as root and forgot afterwards to restore default permission.

Comment: ok, I understand.